# vapor main thread not work

Tags: swift, program-entry-point, vapor

Use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to upload files in the vapor, but [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) did not return the results.After debugging, it is found that GCD's DispatchQueue.main.async method does not execute.

#### reappear

with main.swift

```
let drop = try Droplet()
try drop.setup()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("---main thead---")
}
try drop.run()
```

the code in the GCD will never be executed.who knows what this is the reason.

Comment: please share code for your Droplet class so we can see what setup function is doing

Comment: [Droplet](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) is the vapor class of the framework.

Comment: that means your drop = try Droplet() is also notgeting called.. put a breakpoint there and verify

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I mean DispatchQueue.main.async method is not implemented.

Comment: i know.. there maybe a possibility that this section never got executed by compiler, thats y i am telling you to add a breakpoint there,and check that breakpoint gets triggered or not

Comment: the other can be implemented.only DispatchQueue.main.async method can not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`drop.run()` blocks the main thread. You need to perform your work on a different thread.

Comment: I can not use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to upload file? I tried using [drop.client](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1119), but got a error. do you have a better idea?

Comment: If you make your Alamofire call from a background thread, it should work. See https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/core/overview/#background. If it doesn't, then that's a whole new question - you should ask that separately, and maybe tag it with Alamofire.